# Bs4 not returning any data because it's only returning the commented part of the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So from the following page - https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1995/index.htm

I am trying to scrape the data from the playoffs table but when I target it, it only returns to me the commented part, not the actual data that can be manipulated. For example, I just want to print out all the wildcard games from the table.

```
def loopForData():
    currentYear = 1994
    for i in range(1, 2):
        currentYear += 1
        nfl_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/"+str(currentYear)+"/index.htm"
        result = requests.get(nfl_url).text
        data = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html5lib')
        plyOff_table = data.find(id="all_playoff_results")
        print(plyOff_table)


loopForData()
```

It only returns the following: - Notice how it only gives me the table back commneted. I've tried a couple of parsers know and keep getting the same result lol. Any ideas?

```
<div class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented" id="all_playoff_results">

<div class="section_heading" id="playoff_results_sh">
  <span class="section_anchor" data-label="Playoff Results" id="playoff_results_link"></span><h2>Playoff Results</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div><div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--

<div class="table_container" id="div_playoff_results">

    <table class="sortable stats_table" id="playoff_results" data-cols-to-freeze=",1">
    <caption>Playoff Results Table</caption>

   <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th aria-label="Week number in season" data-stat="week_num" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc sorttable_nosort center" data-tip="Week number in season" >Week</th>
         <th aria-label="Day" data-stat="game_day_of_week" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc left" >Day</th>
         <th aria-label="Date" data-stat="game_date" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" >Date</th>
         <th aria-label="Winner/tie" data-stat="winner" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" >Winner/tie</th>
         <th aria-label="game_location" data-stat="game_location" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" ></th>
         <th aria-label="Loser/tie" data-stat="loser" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" >Loser/tie</th>
         <th aria-label="boxscore_word" data-stat="boxscore_word" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" ></th>
         <th aria-label="Points Scored by the winning team (first one listed)" data-stat="pts_win" scope="col" class=" poptip center" data-tip="Points Scored by the winning team (first one listed)" >PtsW</th>
         <th aria-label="Points Scored by the losing team (second one listed)" data-stat="pts_lose" scope="col" class=" poptip center" data-tip="Points Scored by the losing team (second one listed)" >PtsL</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
<tbody><tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="31" >WildCard</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sat</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz1" >December 30</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/buf/1995.htm">Buffalo Bills</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/mia/1995.htm">Miami Dolphins</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199512300buf.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>37</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >22</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="31" >WildCard</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sat</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz1" >December 30</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/phi/1995.htm">Philadelphia Eagles</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/det/1995.htm">Detroit Lions</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199512300phi.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>58</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >37</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="31" >WildCard</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz1" >December 31</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/clt/1995.htm">Indianapolis Colts</a></strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="game_location" >@</td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/sdg/1995.htm">San Diego Chargers</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199512310sdg.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>35</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >20</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="31" >WildCard</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz1" >December 31</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/gnb/1995.htm">Green Bay Packers</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/atl/1995.htm">Atlanta Falcons</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199512310gnb.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>37</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >20</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="32" >Division</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sat</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz3" >January 6</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/pit/1995.htm">Pittsburgh Steelers</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/buf/1995.htm">Buffalo Bills</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601060pit.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>40</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >21</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="32" >Division</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sat</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz3" >January 6</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/gnb/1995.htm">Green Bay Packers</a></strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="game_location" >@</td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/sfo/1995.htm">San Francisco 49ers</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601060sfo.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>27</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >17</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="32" >Division</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz3" >January 7</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/dal/1995.htm">Dallas Cowboys</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/phi/1995.htm">Philadelphia Eagles</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601070dal.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>30</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >11</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="32" >Division</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz3" >January 7</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/clt/1995.htm">Indianapolis Colts</a></strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="game_location" >@</td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/kan/1995.htm">Kansas City Chiefs</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601070kan.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>10</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >7</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="33" >ConfChamp</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz5" >January 14</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/dal/1995.htm">Dallas Cowboys</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/gnb/1995.htm">Green Bay Packers</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601140dal.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>38</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >27</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="33" >ConfChamp</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz5" >January 14</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/pit/1995.htm">Pittsburgh Steelers</a></strong></td><td class="right iz" data-stat="game_location" ></td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/clt/1995.htm">Indianapolis Colts</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601140pit.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>20</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >16</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="week_num" csk="34" >SuperBowl</th><td class="left " data-stat="game_day_of_week" >Sun</td><td class="left " data-stat="game_date" csk="zz8" >January 28</td><td class="left " data-stat="winner" ><strong><a href="/teams/dal/1995.htm">Dallas Cowboys</a></strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="game_location" >N</td><td class="left " data-stat="loser" ><a href="/teams/pit/1995.htm">Pittsburgh Steelers</a></td><td class="center " data-stat="boxscore_word" ><a href="/boxscores/199601280dal.htm">boxscore</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_win" ><strong>27</strong></td><td class="right " data-stat="pts_lose" >17</td></tr>

</table>


</div>
-->


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is worth learning and to use if needed. However, you don't need it here. The sports-reference.com sites do store some of their tables in the comments. So while it appears to not be static, it actually is, just need to pull out the comments. Which beautfulsoup can do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

def loopForData():
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
    currentYear = 1994
    for i in range(1, 2):
        currentYear += 1
        nfl_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/"+str(currentYear)+"/index.htm"
        result = requests.get(nfl_url, headers=headers).text
        data = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

        comments = data.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
        
        tables = []
        for each in comments:
            if 'table' in str(each):
                try:
                    tables.append(pd.read_html(str(each), attrs = {'id': 'playoff_results'})[0])
                    break
                except:
                    continue
        print(tables[0].to_string())

loopForData()
```

**Output:**

```
         Week  Day         Date           Winner/tie Unnamed: 4            Loser/tie Unnamed: 6  PtsW  PtsL
0    WildCard  Sat  December 30        Buffalo Bills        NaN       Miami Dolphins   boxscore    37    22
1    WildCard  Sat  December 30  Philadelphia Eagles        NaN        Detroit Lions   boxscore    58    37
2    WildCard  Sun  December 31   Indianapolis Colts          @   San Diego Chargers   boxscore    35    20
3    WildCard  Sun  December 31    Green Bay Packers        NaN      Atlanta Falcons   boxscore    37    20
4    Division  Sat    January 6  Pittsburgh Steelers        NaN        Buffalo Bills   boxscore    40    21
5    Division  Sat    January 6    Green Bay Packers          @  San Francisco 49ers   boxscore    27    17
6    Division  Sun    January 7       Dallas Cowboys        NaN  Philadelphia Eagles   boxscore    30    11
7    Division  Sun    January 7   Indianapolis Colts          @   Kansas City Chiefs   boxscore    10     7
8   ConfChamp  Sun   January 14       Dallas Cowboys        NaN    Green Bay Packers   boxscore    38    27
9   ConfChamp  Sun   January 14  Pittsburgh Steelers        NaN   Indianapolis Colts   boxscore    20    16
10  SuperBowl  Sun   January 28       Dallas Cowboys          N  Pittsburgh Steelers   boxscore    27    17
```

Answer (score 1):

You are scraping wrong tag. What you are looking for is stored under:

```
<div class="table_container is_setup" id="div_playoff_results">
```

But since this object is not static, you will not be able to scrape it using `bs4`. Try using `selenium` to get the data you need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1995/index.htm'
chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Retrieve url in headless browser
    driver.get(url)

    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div_playoff_results"]')
    print(data.text)
    driver.close()
```

Above code will return:

```
Week Day Date Winner/tie Loser/tie PtsW PtsL
WildCard Sat December 30 Buffalo Bills Miami Dolphins boxscore 37 22
WildCard Sat December 30 Philadelphia Eagles Detroit Lions boxscore 58 37
WildCard Sun December 31 Indianapolis Colts @ San Diego Chargers boxscore 35 20
WildCard Sun December 31 Green Bay Packers Atlanta Falcons boxscore 37 20
Division Sat January 6 Pittsburgh Steelers Buffalo Bills boxscore 40 21
Division Sat January 6 Green Bay Packers @ San Francisco 49ers boxscore 27 17
Division Sun January 7 Dallas Cowboys Philadelphia Eagles boxscore 30 11
Division Sun January 7 Indianapolis Colts @ Kansas City Chiefs boxscore 10 7
ConfChamp Sun January 14 Dallas Cowboys Green Bay Packers boxscore 38 27
ConfChamp Sun January 14 Pittsburgh Steelers Indianapolis Colts boxscore 20 16
SuperBowl Sun January 28 Dallas Cowboys N Pittsburgh Steelers boxscore 27 17
```

Comment: Thank you Rustem, I've never used Selenium before but I'll go learn it for future. TY